# FluentValidation - passing parameter from one to another rule

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to validate a request by comparing the request value with something that's in our database

I thought I could do something like

```
private SomeValue Values;

     RuleFor(x => x.id).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).MustAsync(async (id, cancellationToken) =>
          {
            var test = await dbContext.Set<Foo>()
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
Values = test.Value;
            return test != null;
          });


 RuleFor(x => x.Values).MustFindAllMandatory(Values);
```

The problem is that the second rule is being applied before the first one is executed, end up having Values = null. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I've tried with When, WhenAsync or event DependencyRule but it seems none of them actually stops evaluating the other rules before the first rule is executed.

Is there anyway to do that? Alternatively. I can query my db for all the the custom rules but I'm quite reluctant do do that

Comment: Why is it required to pass the values to the next rule? Can you call the MustFindAllMandatory from the MustAsync rule?

Comment: Because I have more than 1 rules depending on Values, like a set of 10 different rules.
I've tried something like using RuleFor within MustAsync but it didn't work at all... and throwing an InvalidOperationException, entity type is not part of the model for the current context

Comment: have you tried using "When" ?

Comment: I did also try "When" / "WhenAsync" but it didn't block executing the other rules to be executed. I was expecting something like
RuleFor(...).When(() => Values =  dbContext...; return Values != null, 

RuleFor( ...).MustFindAllMandatory(Values)  
RuleFor(...).MustFindAllMandatorySomethingelse(Values)
...
) 

But that didn't work either, rules are evalualed within the when before "Values" has been evaluated